# How can I destroy THREEJS Scene?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, three.js

I created a Threejs Scene, adding camera, lights and various objects.

The question is simple: how can I destroy scene? Removing from scene all components?

I need to destroy scene because and I do **not** want to delegate the task to the garbage collector.

Comment: What's wrong with garbage collector? Creating a new scene and leaving no variable pointing on the old one should be enough to have it destroyed. Solution below does the same thing anyway. Am I missing something or is this "destroying" actually pointless?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I used this:

```
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.id);// Stop the animation
    this.renderer.domElement.addEventListener('dblclick', null, false); //remove listener to render
    this.scene = null;
    this.projector = null;
    this.camera = null;
    this.controls = null;
    empty(this.modelContainer);
```

The method empty is a substitute to jQuery empty, you can use it:

```
function empty(elem) {
    while (elem.lastChild) elem.removeChild(elem.lastChild);
}
```

Comment: In my project work very well to clean and restart the scene.
If you find somethin more efficient please post it you rolution ;)

Comment: TOP!! I was leaving "cancelAnimationFrame", I didn't know it!

Comment: what is THIS? Canvas parent of Scene?

Comment: In my case all the code is under prorotype and this is the instance of the prototype, this is not relevant, in you case probably you cant ignore it.

Comment: I do not understand what is `this`, `modelContainer` and `projector`.

Comment: Hi Marco, "this" because in my context everything is wrapped in a prototype and this is used for access the projector and modelContainer, you can ignore it if you use global variables. projector is a specific object of threejs, you can find a lot of documentation about it and modelContainer is my root node element of my threejs scene.