# How can I destroy Three.js instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js

In my API I have one component that renders a 3D Model with Three.js, the fact is when I load the page everything is working fine, but when I get into another page it's like three.js is still working behind, so I can even click or type (three.js is still getting your clicks and drags as camera controls).

I've tried to set a function with an interval after loading the page that I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453309/how-can-i-destroy-threejs-scene) that sets to null all the components created of Three.js and deletes the container, that removes all the scene but still can't do a simple click or type a letter.

Once the method destroy() is done, i'm constantly getting an error from the method empty(elem) because lastChild is null as it's obvious, it was removed.

```
function empty(elem) {
            while (elem.lastChild) elem.removeChild(elem.lastChild);
        }
        function destroy(){
            setInterval( () => {
                cancelAnimationFrame(id);// Stop the animation
                renderer.domElement.addEventListener('dblclick', null, false); //remove listener to render
                scene = null;
                light = null;
                camera = null;
                controls = null;
                empty(container);
                container = null;
            }, 2500)
        }

        destroy()
```

I also have this beforeDestroy that removes the div (canvas) when I exit the page.

```
beforeDestroy() {
        var elem = document.querySelector('#divId');
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    },
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Answer (score 0):

The solution was controls.dispose()