# Three.js destroy on new page load

Tags: three.js

I'm helping a friend to set up a Three.js scene on a page in Wordpress that's running on the [Lay](http://laytheme.com/) theme. The theme is using some kind of page transition script that doesn't reload the site when navigating to a different page, creating a new initialization of the Three.js scene each time a new page is injected on the site.

I'm looking for ways to completely remove the whole instance of Three.js when a new page is loaded. So that it gets created from scratch when The Lay theme has this function `window.laytheme.on("newpageshown", function(layoutObj, type, obj){}` that kind of works as a substitute for `window.onload`.

I've tried different methods in order to remove everything, but as my Three.js code unfortunately is a mixed result of copy and pasting from different demos and examples, I'm not quite sure what exactly that needs to be destroyed and how to do it. To be honest I'm not entirely sure how the code is setup and I have very little experience with Three.js and it's lifecycle.

Here's the code creating the scene:

```js
(function($) {

    var base_url = window.location.origin;
    var container, stats;
var camera, scene, renderer, controls, manager, loader, texture;
var mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0;
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
var $currentModel;
var modelName;
var initialGridPosition;
var initialScale;

window.laytheme.on("newpageshown", function(layoutObj, type, obj){
    modelName = $(".modelLink.is-active").data("model-name");
    initialScale = $(".modelLink.is-active").data("model-scale");
    initialGridPosition = $(".modelLink.is-active").data("model-grid-position");

    init();
    animate();
});

function init() {
    container = document.createElement('div');
    container.id = "threejs-container";
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
    camera.position.z = 300;
    camera.position.y = 100;

    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.7);
    scene.add(ambientLight);
    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.3 );
    camera.add( pointLight );
    scene.add(camera);
    // model
    var onProgress = function(xhr) {
        if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
            $("#domLoader").show();
            $("#domLoader").text(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '%');
        }
    };
    // texture
    manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.onProgress = function(item, loaded, total) {
        if (total == loaded) {
            $("#domLoader").hide();
            $(".col--row").removeClass("is-hidden");
            $currentModel = $(".modelLink.is-active");
            $("#meta-title").text('stevns_klint_' + $currentModel.data("model-name"));
            $("#meta-vertices").text($currentModel.data("model-vertices"));
            $("#meta-faces").text($currentModel.data("model-faces"));
            $("#meta-coordinates").text($currentModel.data("model-coordinates"));
            $("#meta-coordinates-url").attr("href", $currentModel.data("model-coordinates-url"));
            $("#meta-date").text($currentModel.data("model-date"));
            $("#meta-images").text($currentModel.data("model-images"));
        }
        console.log(item, loaded, total);
    };
    texture = new THREE.Texture();
    var onProgress = function(xhr) {
        if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
            console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
            $("#domLoader").show();
            $("#domLoader").text(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '%');
        }
    };
    var onError = function() {};
    
    // Create initial model
    loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager)
    loader.setPath(base_url + '/assets/' + modelName +'/').load('texture.jpg', function(image) {
        texture.image = image;
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
    });
    loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
    loader.setPath(base_url + '/assets/' + modelName +'/').load('model.obj', function(object) {
        object.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                child.material.map = texture;
            }
            if( child.material ) {
          child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
      }
        });
        object.scale.x = initialScale;
        object.scale.y = initialScale;
        object.scale.z = initialScale;
        object.name = "mainModel";

        scene.add(object);
    }, onProgress, onError);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var size = 300;
var divisions = 30;

var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( size, divisions, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
scene.add( gridHelper );
gridHelper.position.y = initialGridPosition;

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.screenSpacePanning = true;
    controls.minDistance = 150;
    controls.maxDistance = 300;
    controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
          controls.enableDamping = true;
                controls.enablePan = false;
          controls.autoRotate = true;
          controls.enableKeys = false;
          controls.autoRotateSpeed = 0.04;
          controls.dampingFactor = 0.07;
          controls.rotateSpeed = 0.04;
    controls.update();

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
    
    // Change model on model link click
    $(".modelLink").on("click", function(){
     $(".modelLink").removeClass("is-active");
     $(this).addClass("is-active");
        $(".col--row").addClass("is-hidden");
     var modelName = $(this).data("model-name");
     var modelScale = Number($(this).data("model-scale"));
        var modelGridPosition = $(this).data("model-grid-position");
     loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager)
    loader.setPath(base_url + '/assets/' + modelName +'/').load('texture.jpg', function(image) {
        texture.image = image;
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
    });
     loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
    loader.setPath(base_url + '/assets/' + modelName + '/').load('model.obj', function(object) {
        object.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                child.material.map = texture;
            }
            if( child.material ) {
          child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
      }
        });
        object.scale.x = modelScale;
        object.scale.y = modelScale;
        object.scale.z = modelScale;
        var selectedObject = scene.getObjectByName("mainModel");
        scene.remove( selectedObject );
        object.name = "mainModel";
        gridHelper.position.y = modelGridPosition;
        scene.add(object);
    }, onProgress, onError);
    })
}

function onWindowResize() {
    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    render();
}

function render() {
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

})( jQuery );
```

There code might be some code in there that's irrelevant and have nothing to do with Three.js. But I would appreciate if someone with more experience in the Three.js structure and lifecycle could help me with reading through the script and tell me what parts of the code related to Three.js that needs to be destroyed and how this would be done.

Comment: put it in an iframe

Comment: Ah, I haven’t thought of that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453309/how-can-i-destroy-threejs-scene I suggest this link.